# Facebook Like Notification SubView iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, uitableview, subview

I would like to create a subview which loads notifications similar to Facebook in its iOS app. Does anyone know how to build that?
Thanks!

Something like that:
http://www.techarp.com/article/Apple/Facebook_Notifications/facebook.jpg

Comment: Not sure if this helps u 1. https://github.com/50pixels/FPPopover 2. https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover 3.https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=popover

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a UIPopoverController.

```
UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UIViewControllerNibName" bundle:nil];
viewController.delegate = self;
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navController];             
navController.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(400, 200);
viewController.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(400, 200);
poopover.delegate = self;
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, yourWidth, yourHeight);
[popover presentPopoverFromRect:locRect inView:parentView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft animated:TRUE];
```

viewController is the UIViewController inside the popover, and there you can add, for example, a UITableView to show notifications. UIPopoverController is responsible of showing the popup view. Of course in presentPopoverFromRect: method you have to pass the frame the popover anchors to, the view in which present the popover, the arrow directions allowed and the animate flag in order to show the popover in an animated manner. Finally, with delegation you can communicate to the class that is allocing the popover (self.delegate = self).

Comment: What? Your statement does not make sense.

Comment: what @CRDave meant was UIPopoverController controllers are for use exclusively on iPad devices. check http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html.

Comment: I will suggest to go with Norbert because UIPopoverController in only for iPad and will not work in iPhone